# Is there any way to throw an Exception if Entity is found in Spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring

I was looking something like orElseThrows() but for condition when Entity is found.

Is it the only way how to do this?

```
 var dish = dishRepository.findByName(dishCreationDTO.getName());
    if(dish.isPresent()) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("The same dish is already present in DB");
    }
```

Comment: I think the code you posted is already the best way to do this, optional itself doesn't have helper methods for this

Comment: I think the alternative is to try to insert and let the constraint cause an exception. Nothing wrong with the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> If a value is present, invoke the specified consumer with the value, otherwise do nothing.

The code can be something like that:

```
var dish = dishRepository.findByName(dishCreationDTO.getName());
dish.ifPresent(data -> { 
    throw new EntityNotFoundException("The same dish..."); 
});
```

This code works only if `EntityNotFoundException` is an unchecked exception (extending `RuntimeException`) otherwise doesn't compile.
As you can see the code is not easier to read or shorter than your example, so you can leave the code as it is.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do in a one-liner is the following:

```
 var dish = dishRepository.findByName(dishCreationDTO.getName()).ifPresent(d -> {throw new EntityNotFoundException("The same dish is already present in DB");});
```

So this will throw an exception if an entity exists

Comment: this code doesn't compile because the argument of `ifPresent` is a `Consumer` and doesn't accept a returning code, so you need to wrap it with `{ }` as you can see in my answer

Comment: Yeah I noticed it after posting the answer. Actually it would compile but the exception would not be thrown. I edited it.
I saw your answer after posting mine.

Overall, your answer best covers the question!